# Running script over every file in folder using GDAL in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I'm using GDAL to calculate NDVI mean and max and to find other information about .tif Landsat images acquired from Earth Explorer.  I stacked the bands into a single .tif image and have a working python script to find everything I want to know about the image, however I have many .tif files and I don't want to run the script individually for each file, and I want to make my script automatically run the code over every .tif file I have in the same folder.

The beginning of my script, and how I am accessing the single .tif file looks like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from osgeo import gdal

print("GDAL's version is: " + gdal.__version__)

print (gdal)

print(gdal.GDT_Byte)

dataset = gdal.Open('/Path/To/Folder/Containing/.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

How would I get Python to run the script over every file in this folder automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The python module `glob` is used to get all file names according to the pattern that you give it. The documentation for `glob` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

Within your script you would use `glob` like this:

```
in_directory = r'C:\Data'
files_to_process = glob.glob(os.path.join(in_directory, '*.tif')
for data_path in files_to_process:
    raster_dataset = gdal.Open(data_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    #do your processing on the raster dataset here
```

In the snippet above the `*` is a wildcard to match any string and the `.tif` is static, so this will match all files that end with `.tif`. `glob.glob` returns a list of all files that match your criteria. You can then loop over each filename in the list returned by `glob`. In addition to wildcard matching you can also use regular expressions. `glob` is a very useful module for batch processing and is part of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/), e.g. it is automatically shipped with Python.

Comment: getting error: 

num_bands = dataset.RasterCount

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'

here is the start of my code:

from __future__ import print_function
from osgeo import gdal
import glob
import os
print("GDAL's version is: " + gdal.__version__)
print (gdal)
print(gdal.GDT_Byte)
files = r'/Path/To/Folder/With/.tif/Files'
dataset = glob.glob(os.path.join(files, '*.tif'))
for data in dataset:
    print (dataset)
    num_bands = dataset.RasterCount

Comment: @user71356 the variable `files_to_process` is a list of the file names. You still need to run `gdal.Open()` on the file name, in my example the variable `data_path`  just like you did in your original question. I updated the answer to demonstrate this. In your code above you are calling `.RasterCount` on a list object, just like the AttributeError says a 'list' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'